# Xcode 6 Beta 4: Use of Unresolved Identifier 'NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert'

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

just installed Xcode 6 Beta 4, and this previously compiling code now fails with 'Unresolved Identifier' on every switch of NSFetchedResultsChangeType. I checked the release notes, and of course scavenged through here to see if anyone else has experienced this, but nothing has come up thus far. Any info is appreciated!

thanks!

```
func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeSection sectionInfo: NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo, atIndex sectionIndex: Int, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType) {

    println("Running CoreDataTVC.controllerDidChangeSection")

    switch type {


    case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:

        self.tableView.insertSections(NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex), withRowAnimation: .Fade)

    case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:

        self.tableView.deleteSections(NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex), withRowAnimation: .Fade)

    default:

        return
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When an enumeration

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, NSFetchedResultsChangeType) {
    NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert = 1,
    NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete = 2,
    NSFetchedResultsChangeMove = 3,
    NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate = 4
} ;
```

is mapped to Swift, a common prefix is automatically removed from the enumeration 
values:

```
enum NSFetchedResultsChangeType : UInt {
    case Insert
    case Delete
    case Move
    case Update
}
```

Compare ["Interacting with C APIs"](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH8-XID_13)
in the "Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C" documentation.

So your code should look like this

```
func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeSection sectionInfo: NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo, atIndex sectionIndex: Int, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType) {
    switch type {
        case .Insert:
            self.tableView.insertSections(NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex), withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        case .Delete:
            self.tableView.deleteSections(NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex), withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        default:
            return
    }
}
```

Tip: If you create a "Master-Detail" Application in Xcode with "Use Core Data" selected,
you will get sample code that you can start with.

Comment: Solved!! Thank you so much, works perfectly! I'm surprised I got away with this through betas 2 and 3. Appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The enum NSFetchedResultsChangeType is defined inside of NSFetchedResultsController.

```
enum NSFetchedResultsChangeType : UInt {
    case Insert
    case Delete
    case Move
    case Update
}
```

To access the enum values you can use type of enum followed by the case like this:

```
switch type {  
case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Insert:  
    self.tableView.insertSections(NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex), withRowAnimation: .Fade) 
case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Delete: 
    self.tableView.deleteSections(NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex), withRowAnimation: .Fade)  
default:
    return
}
```

Since you know the Type of type is `NSFetchedResultsChangeType` you can also omit that from the switch cases and just use `case .Insert:` and `case .Delete:`